# Preventing a single file from being overwritten by git commits

Tags: git, heroku, sinatra, immutability, commit

I have a Heroku-hosted Sinatra app, on which users submit data via a form. The data is saved to a JSON file local to the app. I'm using the standard

```
git push heroku master
```

to deploy the app.

Is there a way I can prevent the loss of these user submissions by that file being accidentally overwritten by subsequent commits? I figure that as long as I don't modify the file on my end, it won't be touched by the deployment process. But is there a better way of "locking" the file?

Comment: Put it in a `.gitignore` to be sure it won't be later tracked?

Comment: I've considered that, but then if it gets modified on the server (for any reason) will I be able to roll back the changes?

Comment: Not via git, or else it'll be considered tracked until that point.

Comment: @RomainValeri, that's not how Git ignores work: they only prevent files from being tracked in the first place. Once a file is tracked, it's tracked.

Comment: "The data is saved to a JSON file local to the app"—this won't work on Heroku no matter how you slice it. The ephemeral filesystem will cause your file to be lost every time your dyno restarts, which happens at least once per day.

Comment: @Chris I guess I've been unclear, because it was also my point : if it's one versioned, it's tracked "forever" afterwards.